# How to get base of a random URL with PHP?

Tags: php, function, url

I need a function to get the base of an URL.
(URLs will be submit by users, and could be everything!)
As example:

```
    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law => wikipedia.org
    https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law => wikipedia.org
    http://userpage.chemie.fu-berlin.de/diverse/murphy/murphy_e.html 
=> fu-berlin.de
    http://www.murphyslawpetone.co.nz/ => murphyslawpetone.co.nz
```

Comment: So what you are looking for is the "registrable part" of the domain / host name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a domain name parser for that which has information about the ever changing list of public suffixes, sometimes incorrectly referred to as "TLDs". Otherwise you will get wrong results in some cases. I suggest you take a look at Jemery Kendalls [php-domain-parser](https://github.com/jeremykendall/php-domain-parser/) on github. It comes with a good documentation and examples.

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Pdp\PublicSuffixListManager;
use Pdp\Parser;
// Obtain an instance of the parser
$pslManager = new PublicSuffixListManager();
$parser = new Parser($pslManager->getList());

$url = 'http://www.murphyslawpetone.co.nz/';
$urlObj = $parser->parseUrl($url);
$hostObj = $url->host;
$baseUrl = $host->registerableDomain;
echo $baseUrl;
```

This will output `murphyslawpetone.co.nz` which is what you are looking for, if I got your question right...

---

This approach is much more reliable than the typical solutions you see:

1. it does not take the whole host name (which is not what you are asking for)
2. it is able to handle public suffixes consisting of more than a single label

You will have to update the list of public suffixes from time to time, since it actually changes. Not on a daily base, but you should update maybe once a month...